# How to use preferences in tornadofx.

Tags: tornadofx

I am trying to use preferences in tornadofx . but documentation has very few about it. 
"unresolved references" to "preferences".
From where to import preferences ?
Please give and clear example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Preferences API in JavaFX allows you store store arbitrary configuration options in an OS dependent way. It's a direct alternative to the `config` functionality in TornadoFX. This example retrieves and stores a value from the default Perferences node:

```
class UserEditor : View("User Editor") {
    val name = SimpleStringProperty()

    init {
        preferences {
            name.value = get("name", "Default Name")
        }
    }

    override val root = form {
        fieldset {
            field("Name") {
                textfield(name)
            }
        }
        button("Save").action {
            preferences {
                put("name", name.value)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

TornadoFX merely facilitates easier access to the Preferences store available to JavaFX applications. You can also pass a specific node name as parameter to the preferences function.

Answer (score 1):

Try the official guide to TornadoFX `config` [here](https://edvin.gitbooks.io/tornadofx-guide/content/part2/Config_Settings_and_State.html).

It shows an example of configuration settings applied to the user login form, communication with ViewModel, and other useful stuff.